# jQuery show/close content when radio button selected

Tags: jquery, radio-button

Hey I am looking for a very simply jQuery code that displays a hidden div when a certain radio button is selected, and hides that div if that radio button is "deselected".

I figured it out how to make it work with checkboxes but I don't know why it won't work with radio buttons as well.

Here is the code which works fine with checkboxes:

```
$("#radio-id").click(function(){
   // If checked
    if ($("#radio-id").is(":checked")) {
        //show the hidden div
        $("#div-id").show("slide");
    } else {
        //otherwise, hide it
        $("#div-id").hide("slide");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ($("#radio-id").is(":checked")) {

     //Put code here

} else{

     //Put code here

}
```

It seems you've made a syntax error. I don't think divs can be checked.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in the first post. I edited it already. It is exactly what you wrote but it won't work..

Comment: I see, I see. When I removed the second part in your jsFiddle example (the #stinch part in the JavaScript section). It won't work anymore. Because I in my form I have many radio buttons. So basically I have to write a JS code for each of them? Because when using checkboxes I just can define one textbox to show/hide content depending on whether it is checked or not. Is there an alternative?

Comment: When using checkboxes I have no problem. But my question to you was: why do you need 2 jQuery functions (as in ur first jsfiddle example) to my it work. As you can see, when using checkboxes, a simple if-else statement does the trick. But when using radio buttons, it won't work. I have many checkboxes (around 10) and only when clicking 1 radio button I want a hidden div to show up. But in your jsFiddle example, you had to write a separate jQuery function for the second "No Bunz" button. Is there an easier way to achieve this? Sorry for being so curious, but your help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Hey thanks a lot :) I think I am overworking on this project and start to mess up things. Anwyays, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
$("#radio-id").click(function(){
   // If checked
    if ($("#radio-id").is(":checked")) {
        //show the hidden div
        $("#div-id").show("slide");
    } else {
        //otherwise, hide it
        $("#div-id").hide("slide");
    }
});
```

**Update based on your jsfiddle:**

```
<style>
  #div-id{display:none} 
</style>

<div id="testing" >
  <input type ="radio" id="radio-id" name="link" >Option 1</input>
  <input type ="radio" name="link" >Option 2</input>
</div>
<div id="div-id"> IT WORKS!<div>

<script type="text/javascript" >
$("#testing").click(function(){
if ($("#radio-id").is(":checked")) {

        //show the hidden div
         $("#div-id").show("slide");

    } else {


        $("#div-id").hide("slide");
    }
});
</script>
```

Your jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/YZCN3

New jsfiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/YZCN3/2/

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in the first post. I edited it already. It is exactly what you wrote but it won't work...

Comment: was your problem fixed? if yes please mark the answer as resolving answer.

Comment: The problem with this solution is: when ticking the radio button the hidden content displays without problem. But when choosing another radio button (from the same "name group" the div won't disappear). Do you know what I mean?

Comment: then you will have to catch the click by group name probably, I did not understand your issue could you put your code in jsfiddle that I can understand well your issue ?

Comment: Hey, here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YZCN3/
As you can see, when clicking on option 1 the concent displays, but when clicking on option 2 (after clicking option 1) the div won't disappear :(

Comment: You already marked this problem as solved, however I will update my solution based on your jsfiddle, you are checking the click on only one radio option, i replaced the check on another div which contains all of them.
http://jsfiddle.net/YZCN3/2/